# Creating multiple connectors via models in their own namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, connection, models

I have an application written in PHP using the ZendFramework, containing a library of "Connections", for example, MySQL, CSV, Twitter etc.

If a user signs up, they can connect to any data sources, say they pick a MySQL connector and a Twitter connector.

Based on the details they have entered in my UI, I would then  connect to those datasources and retrieve the data they asked for.

I was hoping to set this up in Ruby on Rails but I'm not sure how. Basically what I want is:

```
@twitter_connection = Twitter.somefunction 
@mysql_connection = Mysql.somefunction
```

The Twitter and MySQL models above would be in their own namespace. I called it "Connections" in my app. Can I have a namespace like that in Rails and store all the connection models in the `/app/connections` folder, so it would be:

```
/app/connections/mysql.rb
/app/connections/twitter.rb
```

Then, in those models, I would make the appropriate connection, whether it would be to MySQL, or an API like Twitter. Either way, the model would make the connection to the source and return whatever data I need.

Is that possible?

//Edit from comments

I have a class under '/app/connection/classname.rb'

The file contents are:

```
class Classname
   def function
   end
end
```

How do I access this class in a controller.

`@variable = Classname.function` doesn't work.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but you, as the developer, have to write all the code to make it happen. It won't spring into existence magically, and will take a thorough knowledge of Rails and how it connects to the various data sources you want to support.

Comment: Yes I get that. I just would like to know how to structure the file So I can access it correctly in my controller.

Comment: I dont need help with the connections themselves. I need to work out how to properly structure the models. Right now, @twitter_connection = Twitter.somefunction doesn't work. How can I setup Rails so It recognises the Twitter Model??

Comment: Have you written code or are you asking how to do it? On Stack Overflow we really expect you to post code you're having a problem with, and explain what you intend it to do and what problem you've encountered.

Comment: Sure no problem. I'll put it back in my post

Comment: in your edit, the function is an instance function, so you need an instance of Class to call it, ie `Class.new.function`. to call it your way, you need to make it a static method, `def self.function;end`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried like you said making a new instance of the class. But it doesn't seem to able to find the class in my folder /app/connections/classname.rb I do '@class = Class.new' but how does it know that Class belongs to /app/connections/classname.rb?

Comment: Can I give it its own namespace or something?

Comment: Hey thanks quandrum. That really helped. All done!